# Calculating homography matrix using arbitrary known geometrical relations

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, measurement, homography

I am using OpenCV for an optical measurement system. I need to carry out a perspective transformation between two images, captured by a digital camera. In the field of view of the camera I placed a set of markers (which lie in a common plane), which I use as corresponding points in both images. Using the markers' positions I can calculate the homography matrix. The problem is, that the measured object, whose images I actually want to transform is positioned in a small distance from the markers and in parallel to the markers' plane. I can measure this distance.

My question is, how to take that distance into account when calculating the homography matrix, which is necessary to perform the perspective transformation.

In my solution it is a strong requirement not to use the measured object points for calculation of homography (and that is why I need other markers in the field of view).

Please let me know if the description is not precise.

[image]

Presented in the figure is the exemplary image.

The red rectangle is the measured object. It is physically placed in a small distance behind the circular markers.

I capture images of the object from different camera's positions. The measured object can deform between each acquisition. Using circular markers, I want to transform the object's image to the same coordinates. I can measure the distance between object and markers but I do not know, how should I modify the homography matrix in order to work on the measured object (instead of the markers).

Comment: A photo would be better than a thousand words

Comment: Why are you trying to find the homography? What will you do with it? I am asking this as it is hard to understand your question. I think I do understand it now. I don't know an answer right now but maybe a different approach will get you a quicker answer, that's why I'd like to know what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

This question is quite old, but it is interesting and it might be useful to someone.

**First, here is how I understood the problem presented in the question:**

You have two images I<sub>1</sub> and I<sub>2</sub> acquired by the same digital camera at two different positions. These images both show a set of markers which all lie in a common plane p<sub>m</sub>. There is also a measured object, whose visible surface lies in a plane p<sub>o</sub> parallel to the marker's plane but with a small offset. You computed the homography H<sup>m</sup><sub>12</sub> mapping the markers positions in I<sub>1</sub> to the corresponding markers positions in I<sub>2</sub> and you measured the offset d<sub>m-o</sub> between the planes p<sub>o</sub> and p<sub>m</sub>. From that, you would like to calculate the homography H<sup>o</sup><sub>12</sub> mapping points on the measured object in I<sub>1</sub> to the corresponding points in I<sub>2</sub>.

**A few remarks on this problem:**

First, notice that an homography is a relation between image points, whereas the distance between the markers' plane and the object's plane is a distance in world coordinates. Using the latter to infer something about the former requires to have a *metric* estimation of the camera poses, i.e. you need to determine the *euclidian* and *up-to-scale* relative position & orientation of the camera for each of the two images. The *euclidian* requirement implies that the digital camera must be calibrated, which should not be a problem for an "optical measurement system". The *up-to-scale* requirement implies that the true 3D distance between two given 3D points must be known. For instance, you need to know the true distance l<sub>0</sub> between two arbitrary markers.

Since we only need the *relative* pose of the camera for each image, we may choose to use a 3D coordinate system centered and aligned with the coordinate system of the camera for I<sub>1</sub>. Hence, we will denote the projection matrix for I<sub>1</sub> by P<sub>1</sub> = K<sub>1</sub> * [ I | 0 ]. Then, we denote the projection matrix for I<sub>2</sub> (in the same 3D coordinate system) by P<sub>2</sub> = K<sub>2</sub> * [ R<sub>2</sub> | t<sub>2</sub> ]. We will also denote by D<sub>1</sub> and D<sub>2</sub> the coefficients modeling lens distortion respectively for I<sub>1</sub> and I<sub>2</sub>.

As a single digital camera acquired both I<sub>1</sub> and I<sub>2</sub>, you may assume that K<sub>1</sub> = K<sub>2</sub> = K and D<sub>1</sub> = D<sub>2</sub> = D. However, if I<sub>1</sub> and I<sub>2</sub> were acquired with a long delay between the acquisitions (or with a different zoom, etc), it will be more accurate to consider that two different camera matrices and two sets of distortion coefficients are involved.

**Here is how you could approach such a problem:**

The steps in order to estimate P<sub>1</sub> and P<sub>2</sub> are as follows:

1. Estimate K<sub>1</sub>, K<sub>2</sub> and D<sub>1</sub>, D<sub>2</sub> via calibration of the digital camera
2. Use D<sub>1</sub> and D<sub>2</sub> to correct images I<sub>1</sub> and I<sub>2</sub> for lens distortion, then determine the marker positions in the corrected images
3. Compute the fundamental matrix F<sub>12</sub> (mapping points in I<sub>1</sub> to epilines in I<sub>2</sub>) from the corresponding markers positions and infer the essential matrix E<sub>12</sub> = K<sub>2</sub><sup>T</sup> * F<sub>12</sub> * K<sub>1</sub>
4. Infer R<sub>2</sub> and t<sub>2</sub> from E<sub>12</sub> and one point correspondence (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22807039/decomposition-of-essential-matrix-validation-of-the-four-possible-solutions-for/22808118#22808118) to a related question). At this point, you have an *affine* estimation of the camera poses, but not an *up-to-scale* one since t<sub>2</sub> has unit norm.
5. Use the measured distance l<sub>0</sub> between two arbitrary markers to infer the correct norm for t<sub>2</sub>.
6. For the best accuracy, you may refine P<sub>1</sub> and P<sub>2</sub> using a bundle adjustment, with K<sub>1</sub> and ||t<sub>2</sub>|| fixed, based on the corresponding marker positions in I<sub>1</sub> and I<sub>2</sub>.

At this point, you have an accurate *metric* estimation of the camera poses P<sub>1</sub> = K<sub>1</sub> * [ I | 0 ] and P<sub>2</sub> = K<sub>2</sub> * [ R<sub>2</sub> | t<sub>2</sub> ]. Now, the steps to estimate H<sup>o</sup><sub>12</sub> are as follows:

7. Use D<sub>1</sub> and D<sub>2</sub> to correct images I<sub>1</sub> and I<sub>2</sub> for lens distortion, then determine the marker positions in the corrected images (same as 2. above, no need to re-do that) and estimate H<sup>m</sup><sub>12</sub> from these corresponding positions
8. Compute the 3x1 vector v describing the markers' plane p<sub>m</sub> by solving this linear equation: Z * H<sup>m</sup><sub>12</sub> = K<sub>2</sub> * ( R<sub>2</sub> - t<sub>2</sub> * v<sup>T</sup> ) * K<sub>1</sub><sup>-1</sup> (see HZ00 chapter 13, result 13.5 and equation 13.2 for a reference on that), where Z is a scaling factor. Infer the distance to origin d<sub>m</sub> = ||v|| and the normal n = v / ||v||, which describe the markers' plane p<sub>m</sub> in 3D.
9. Since the object plane p<sub>o</sub> is parallel to p<sub>m</sub>, they have the same normal n. Hence, you can infer the distance to origin d<sub>o</sub> for p<sub>o</sub> from the distance to origin d<sub>m</sub> for p<sub>m</sub> and from the measured plane offset d<sub>m-o</sub>, as follows: d<sub>o</sub> = d<sub>m</sub> ± d<sub>m-o</sub> (the sign depends of the relative position of the planes: positive if p<sub>m</sub> is closer to the camera for I<sub>1</sub> than p<sub>o</sub>, negative otherwise).
10. From n and d<sub>o</sub> describing the object plane in 3D, infer the homography H<sup>o</sup><sub>12</sub> = K<sub>2</sub> * ( R<sub>2</sub> - t<sub>2</sub> * n<sup>T</sup> / d<sub>o</sub> ) * K<sub>1</sub><sup>-1</sup> (see HZ00 chapter 13, equation 13.2)
11. The homography H<sup>o</sup><sub>12</sub> maps points on the measured object in I<sub>1</sub> to the corresponding points in I<sub>2</sub>, where both I<sub>1</sub> and I<sub>2</sub> are assumed to be corrected for lens distortion. If you need to map points from and to the original distorted image, don't forget to use the distortion coefficients D<sub>1</sub> and D<sub>2</sub> to transform the input and output points of H<sup>o</sup><sub>12</sub>.

The reference I used:

[HZ00] "Multiple view geometry for computer vision", by R.Hartley and A.Zisserman, 2000.