# find camera rotation using two images

Tags: java, opencv, computer-vision

### Updated

I have a *GoPro Hero4 Black* mounted on a drone receiving the drone's telemetry, which tends to be inaccurate at times. I need to verify the telemetry by calculating the camera's rotation and translation from two different frames.

I have calculated the *essential matrix* using the intrinsic parameters, that I extracted from my *camera matrix*, which I had gotten by the *OpenCV* chessboard calibration.

**Problem**
Now the results I am getting are rubbish unless I am comparing the same photo to itself. They also differ based on which feature detector I use or whether I use *RANSAC* or *LMEDS* but I am pretty sure that key point matching itself works well. Therefore I believe I

***Either*** decompose the *essential matrix* and retrieve its corresponding angles incorrectly

***Or*** my camera is not calibrated well even though the reprojection error was 0.23.

I, however, have no idea how to verify which of them is true (or if any). I have found other ways of the *essential matrix* decomposition such as this one [Decomposition of Essential Matrix: Validation of the four possible solutions for R and T](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22807039/decomposition-of-essential-matrix-validation-of-the-four-possible-solutions-for) and I do not know what the difference is between this approach and mine - using *org.opencv.calib3d.Calib3d.decomposeEssentialMat(..)*. Anyone care to clarify?

**Question 1:** Could anyone please check if my angle retrieval is correct?

**Question 2:** I am not sure how to check if my camera calibration is correct but I am posting it below along with its parameters retrieved by *Calib3d.calibrationMatrixValues(..)*. I think it is not since the field of view retrieved is different than the one of my camera's specs. Could you please confirm this?

I am using *Java* and *OpenCV 3.1*.

I appreciate your help.

### Main function

```
        // Match keypoints
        // ....
        MatOfPoint2f firstImageMop2f = new MatOfPoint2f();
        firstImageMop2f.fromList(firstImageList);

        MatOfPoint2f secondImageMop2f = new MatOfPoint2f();
        secondImageMop2f.fromList(secondImageList);

        Mat essentialMat = org.opencv.calib3d.Calib3d.findEssentialMat(firstImageMop2f, secondImageMop2f,
                3.5714310113232735, new Point(3.1427346523449033, 2.383214663142159),
                org.opencv.calib3d.Calib3d.RANSAC, 0.999, 3);
        decomposeEssential(essentialMat);
```

### Decompose Essential

```
private void decomposeEssential(Mat essentialMat) {
    Mat firstRotation = new Mat();
    Mat secondRotation = new Mat();
    Mat translation = new Mat();
    org.opencv.calib3d.Calib3d.decomposeEssentialMat(essentialMat, firstRotation, secondRotation, translation);
    printRotationMatrix(firstRotation, "Rotation matrix");
    printRotationMatrix(secondRotation, "Rotation matrix");
    printGeneralMatrix(translation, "Translation");
}
```

### Print rotation matrix

```
private void printRotationMatrix(Mat matrix, String description) {
    double x, y, z;
    double sy = Math.sqrt(matrix.get(0, 0)[0] * matrix.get(0, 0)[0]
                            + matrix.get(1, 0)[0] * matrix.get(1, 0)[0]);
    boolean singular = sy < 1e-6;

    if (!singular) {
        System.out.println(" as a non singular matrix");
        x = Math.atan2(matrix.get(2, 1)[0], matrix.get(2, 2)[0]); //roll
        y = Math.atan2(-matrix.get(2, 0)[0], sy); // pitch
        z = Math.atan2(matrix.get(1, 0)[0], matrix.get(0, 0)[0]); // yaw
    } else {
        System.out.println(" as a singular matrix");
        x = Math.atan2(-matrix.get(2, 1)[0], matrix.get(2, 2)[0]);
        y = Math.atan2(-matrix.get(2, 0)[0], sy);
        z = 0;
    }

    System.out.println("Axes angles: ");
    System.out.println("x (roll): " + Math.toDegrees(x));
    System.out.println("y (pitch): " + Math.toDegrees(y));
    System.out.println("z (yaw): " + Math.toDegrees(z));
}
```

### Camera matrix

```
    740.9127543750064 0.0 651.9773670991048 
    0.0 736.5104868078901 377.12407856315485 
    0.0 0.0 1.0
```

### Calib3d.calibrationMatrixValues(cameraMatrix, new Size(1280, 720), 6.17, 4.55, output parameters...)

```
    FoVx: 81.64086856941297
    FoVy: 52.09797490556325
    Focal length: 3.5714310113232735
    Principal point of view; x: 3.1427346523449033, y: 2.383214663142159
    Aspect ratio: 0.9940583185521892
```

Comment: findHomography only finds a perspective transform between two planes. If the points you are taking pictures of aren't part of a planar surface, your calculated values will be bogus. The Essential matrix is more what you are looking for. You can decompose it to its rotation and translation.

Comment: Ok, I have tried a new approach but still some things are not entirely clear to me. I edited my question above accordingly.

Comment: focal length and principal point offset are intrinsic parameters. you usually get them through camera calibration: http://ksimek.github.io/2012/08/14/decompose/

Comment: I think I have them even though I'm not sure about some other things. I edited my question once again.